# how do you extract an the shape of an object?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to make a autonomous car in a game but to do that i need to extract the shape of the road.

this will help you under stand:

[image]

so is there a way to classify if the road is bent to the right or the left?.
if so can you do a event based on if it is right or left

this is the output if i grayscale this image:

[image]

it  takes the lane good but with the shadow and car umm... you can see.

but the road is impossible to truly classify, with out looking the yellow lane.

Comment: Shouldn't the game already know by itself whether the road is bent left or right? It must know this in order to draw it.

Comment: No its a game like gta5 i did not make it so there is no way for me to get data from the game.

Comment: That a) doesn't mean anything to anyone who hasn't played it and b) opens up a huge 3D can of worms that has very little to do with the 2D image you posted. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Can the car leave the road?

Comment: i posted a better picture

Comment: Ok, so to clarify: there is some game from a 3rd party and you want to write a program that can look at the screen and control the car automatically? If so, that's a fairly complicated task that can't be answered in a single question, but if I was to give you a hint in the right direction I would look at using edge detection, color filtering, or other computer vision techniques. If you can use that to determine the position of the car relative to the yellow line you should be able to steer the car.